# Store Time in database

Tags: android, sqlite

i am new to android, i want to store the time and retrieve the time in sq lite database. Any one help me to solve the problem.

Comment: @Klaus +1. Google is your friend, @Gnanaprakasam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial on Android dev documentation , [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), that show how to use it

Comment: i don't see any paragraph about 'How to store Datetime in SQLite' there

Comment: You seriously need step-by-step example for it? That linked example is easy to modify...

Comment: We need to wait for OP specifics

Comment: he not me :) i'm just trying to understand him and maybe i'm wrong and he knows nothing about sqlite or he is just asking how to store datetime type in sqlite coz there is no such thing as datetime type there :)

Answer (score 6):

Knowing that you will never accept an answer but willing to still help:

Create a column, date as Integer, and store the time as a number (in milliseconds). That is how all of the tutorials and example apps do it.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.html

Example:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + NotePad.Notes.TABLE_NAME + " ("
               + NotePad.Notes._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
               + NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " TEXT,"
               + NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE + " TEXT,"
               + NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_CREATE_DATE + " INTEGER," // <- see
               + NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_MODIFICATION_DATE + " INTEGER"
               + ");");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

look into sqlite documentation http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime